# Convert all numeric values in dataframe to float but leave strings unchanged

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose I have this data frame:

```
pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,'3', "4-Very Good"], "B":['1', '2', '3}'], "C": ['Apple', 'Ball', 'Cat'], "D": [1,4,"5-Excellent"]})
```

**Column “A”:** 
1) I want both 1 and ‘3’ to be converted to float ; 2) do not want to convert ‘4-Very Good’ to NaN.

**Column “B”:** I want to make each of “1”, “2”, “3” to float.

**Column “C”:** should be unchanged.

**Column “D”:** 
1)I want to change “1” and “4” to float; 2)do not want to convert “4-Very Good” to NaN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is casting to `float` with [`pd.to_numeric`](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas+to_numeric&rlz=1C1CHBD_enES868ES868&oq=pandas+to_numeric&aqs=chrome..69i57j35i39j0l6.2536j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) all existing numbers, and `fillna` back with `df`:

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').fillna(df)

             A   B      C            D
0            1   1  Apple            1
1            3   2   Ball            4
2  4-Very Good  3}    Cat  5-Excellent
​
```

---

An appreciation from @aLollz: By simply doing `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')` here we are not solving the problem. When an entire column cannot be cast to `float`, it remains unchanged. We must `coerce` the errors so the column becomes of type float, and then `fillna` with the string values, ending up with an `object` dtype column in the case any values are filled, but with the numerical vales remaining as floats.

Comment: You can do this using ignore instead and avoid the coercion and filling after, eg: `df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')`

Comment: No worries - will delete this and my other comment in a mo'.

Comment: Just checked with that first `1` in `A` and you're right @ALollz

Comment: Ooops... sorry yatu - should have seen that :( Good catch @ALollz!

Comment: Guess then `df.applymap(lambda v: pd.to_numeric(v, errors='ignore'))` - that'll do the same as a fillna after, but whether it's desirable or any better... and there's still the question of why one would want to do this anyway on values... but... guess that's for another day

Comment: Hmm my guess though is that by acting on an element-wise basis you'd be killing a bit performance here @JonClements

Comment: Got for apply/fillna `4.88 ms ± 137 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`and for `.applymap` - `2.92 ms ± 44.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)`

Comment: Yeh but it scales much worse @jon try with `df = pd.concat([df]*1000, axis=0)`

Comment: oh ouch ouch ouch - you're completely right - that's just horrible... so yeah... definitely you were right here and my suggestion was misleading at best - sorry again!

Comment: @yatu many thanks for your help. However, the values in column B are stored as int, even if I pass downcast = ‘float’ parameter.

Comment: Maybe your pandas version? Testing with your sample df I'm getting floats @PrashantSharma

Comment: Sadly, I get:
 A    object
B     int64
C    object
D    object
dtype: object
Was using older version of pandas, just updated to 1.0.3. 
And this was what I did: df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce', downcast='float').fillna(df).dtypes

Comment: Ah, yes of course. The columns will be of dtype object. This is panda's dtype for mixed dtype columns. Go check the individual numbers and you'll see that they are floats @PrashantSharma

Comment: Individual numbers are floats in the object dtype columns, which is fantastic. However, the column B is int64. Are you getting individual numbers in column B also as float?

Comment: @yatu I solved using this but I know this is far from being an elegant solution: 
```
for index, value in df.dtypes.items():
    if value == 'int64':
        df[index] = df[index].astype('float’)```